# CSS media property doesn't overwrite

Tags: css

I'm trying to specify specific `display` tag according to width of the page. Typically, it is of `flex` but less than `437px` I want to specify the property as `grid`.

Css,

```
.test {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

@media all /*and (min-width:960px) and*/ (max-width: 437px) {
    /* put your css styles in here */
    .test {
        display: grid;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there a comment expression in between the `@media all` query?

Comment: @m4n0 it is of no importance.

Comment: Then, for the sake of minimising, and removing the unnecessary, code in your question it shouldn’t be there.

Comment: Did you notice, that `and (min-width:960px) and ` wasn’t escaped by the comment according to StackOverflow’s markup?

Comment: @snr How are you so sure about the importance?

Comment: @mpm it is the mistake of SO, not mine.

Comment: I think you accidentally escaped one “and” to much in the `@media`-query

Comment: Ah, sorry, @J4R already wrote that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you removed a little to much with your commenting. The "and" is missing.

it has to be:

```css
.test {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

@media all /*and (min-width:960px) */  and (max-width: 437px) {
    /* put your css styles in here */
    .test {
        display: grid;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
```